# Particles physics - Projection matrices

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-matrices, chirality

I'm struggling with a question were I'm asked to simply the following expression such that my result only involves one projection matrix.

$$P_L \not p \not k P_L $$

Where $$P_L = (\frac{1-\gamma_5}{2})$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\{\gamma^\mu, \gamma_5\}=0$. What can you say then about $P_L\gamma^\mu$? Moreover, being $P_L$ a projector, you have the property that $P_L^2=P_L$. With this two ideas in mind you can see that the answer is trivial.

Comment: $\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma_5\} = \gamma^5\gamma_\mu + \gamma^\mu\gamma_5=0$ ?

Comment: So $P_L\gamma^\mu = \gamma^\mu P_R$ ? @davide-morgante

Comment: @Harvey B  . Yes; now braid another gamma matrix on top of this.

Comment: $\gamma^\mu P_R \gamma^\mu$ ? @CosmasZachos I'm not sure where to go after this?

Comment: @HarveyB, yes $P_L\gamma^\mu =\gamma^\mu P_R$. Then $P_L\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu = \gamma^\mu P_R \gamma^\nu = ?$

Comment: $\gamma^\mu P^R \gamma^\nu = (2g_{\mu\nu}-\gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu) P_R$ ? @DavideMorgante

Comment: @HarveyB No. You don't need to commute the gamma matrices, you only need to commute the projection operator again.

Comment: Oh so $\gamma^\mu P_R \gamma^\nu = \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu P_L$? @DavideMorgante

Comment: Which then leads to $ \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu P_L P_L = \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu (P_L )^2 = \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu P_L$?

Comment: @HarveyB Yes, that's it.

Comment: So, $P_L \not p \not k P_L = \not p \not k P_L  $ Rock n roll, thank you! @DavideMorgante